# gridtext::element_markdown doesn't apply margin with css selector

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggtext

I'm trying to define different margins for x-axis labels in ggplot2 using css syntax, as allowed by ggtext package. I created an object with the CSS selector and used `element_markdown()` for `axis.text.x`. However, nothing happens to the plot.

Here is an example:

```
    library(ggplot2)
    library(ggtext)
    df <- data.frame(x = runif(n = 20, min = 1, max = 10),
                     y = runif(n = 20, min = 1, max = 10))
    num1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    num2 <- c(6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
    labels <- rep(NA, 10)
    labels[num1] <- paste0("<span style='margin-top:16px'>", num1, "</span>")
    labels[num2] <- paste0("<span style='margin-top:64px'>", num2, "</span>")
    
    ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
      geom_point() +
      scale_x_continuous(name = "",
                         limits = c(0, 10),
                         breaks = seq(1, 10, 1),
                         labels = labels) +
      theme(axis.text.x = ggtext::element_markdown())
```

[image: Plot 01]

We can see that labels didn't change their position. But, when I tried other selector, i.e., `font-size`, it worked.

Example:

```
labels[num1] <- paste0("<span style='font-size:12px'>", num1, "</span>")
labels[num2] <- paste0("<span style='font-size:6px'>", num2, "</span>")

    ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
      geom_point() +
      scale_x_continuous(name = "",
                         limits = c(0, 10),
                         breaks = seq(1, 10, 1),
                         labels = labels) +
      theme(axis.text.x = ggtext::element_markdown())
```

[image: Plot 02]

Comment: Possible due to [`ggtext` ... implements only an extremely limited subset of Markdown/HTML/CSS](https://github.com/wilkelab/ggtext)

Comment: Only "The CSS properties color, font-size, and font-family are currently supported." See https://wilkelab.org/ggtext/articles/theme_elements.html.

Comment: @user20650 and stefan, thanks for the answers!